# call private function in the constructor of module pattern

Tags: javascript

This is my first attempt to write a module in java script.

```
myClass = (function() {
    //private members
    SELF = {};
    //constructor
    (function _init()
    {
        SELF.private_member = 10;
    });

    function _print()
    {
        return SELF.private_member;
    }

    return function() {
       _init();
       this.Print = _print;
    };

})();

var obj = new myClass();
```

I get a error that function _init() is not defined (chrome). How can this be achieved?

Comment: Remove parentheses around `_init` function definition (which is in fact a *function expression*).

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. Does the semi colon matter? does it make an expression. It works with the semi colon

Comment: Do you recognise that there is only one `SELF` object regardless of how many `new myClass` instances you create? I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @Bergi: you are right, that's not what i want. I need one SELF object for each instance? Please tell me how should it be done?

Comment: @ProgramCpp: Make `SELF` an argument to all your instance-related private functions, and pass `this` to them whereever you call them. Use closures in your constructor.

Comment: @Bergi: A brief answer with code sample would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is the way that the `init` function is declared. The below samples will work.

(A) without the brackets:

```
myClass = (
function() {
    //private members
    SELF = {};

    //constructor
    //this function is executed every time an object is created
    function _init() {
        SELF.private_member = 10;
    }

    function _print() {
        return SELF.private_member;
    }

    return function() {
       _init();
       this.Print = _print;
    };

})();
```

(B) The second option is to call the _init() function anonymously like this:

```
myClass = (function() {
    //private members
    SELF = {};

    //constructor
    (function() {
        SELF.private_member = 10;
    })();

    function _print() {
        return SELF.private_member;
    }

    return function() {
       this.Print = _print;
    };
})();

// Better syntax for example B)
myClass = (function() {
    //private members
    SELF = {};

    function _print() {
        return SELF.private_member;
    }

    //constructor; right before the return statement
    //this code is executed ONCE only
    SELF.private_member = 10;

    return function() {
       //this code is exectuted every time an object is created
       this.Print = _print;
    };
})();
```

I would use the first example, as sample (B) can be a little tricky: The constructor is called instantly (i.e. before the function `_print()` is defined), so you have to take care that any functions/variables that the constructor uses are above the constructor function!

With (A) you don't have this problem.

**Functional differences**:

(A) The constructor function _init() is called every time you create a new object. 
Technically this is very close to a real constructor as in other object oriented programming languages.

(B) The constructor code is only called once, when you declare the class. Technically this is not a constructor here but actually some class initialization code.

Comment: "The problem in your code is the way that the init function is declared" --- it would be really helpful if you explained to the OP why it happens. Just "remove the parentheses to make it work" does not teach OP anything.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer option A since i need all my java script files to be loaded and will need resources from other files in the constructor.

Comment: I don't think B is functionally equivalent either

Comment: @zerkms I think providing two working examples is educational enough for most people to understand how syntax is supposed to look like ;-) I cannot explain the issue more detailled than "syntax is wrong", but of course I'm happy if someone adds more details or an explanation

Answer (score -1):

Couple of questions

1. Why is `_init()` a constructor? Constructor should be the one which you are returning.
2. Any particular reason you have grouped (named function expression) the `_init()` function?

Ignoring the answers what you want to get can be achieved in two ways

```
myClass = (function() {
    //private members
    SELF = {};
    //constructor
    (function _init()
    {
        SELF.private_member = 10;
    })();

    function _print()
    {
        return SELF.private_member;
    }

    return function() {
       this.Print = _print;
    };

})();

var obj = new myClass();
```

and

```
myClass = (function() {
    //private members
    SELF = {};
    //constructor
    function _init()
    {
        SELF.private_member = 10;
    }

    function _print()
    {
        return SELF.private_member;
    }

    return function() {
       _init();
       this.Print = _print;
    };

})();

var obj = new myClass();
```

Comment: 1. _init is not my constructor, it the private member which I am trying to call from the constructor. I comment so in the code because it is always called by the constructor to construct my object.
2. I did not intent to do it.

Comment: I see. You can read more about it [here](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/different-ways-of-defining-functions-in-javascript-this-is-madness/) and [here](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/)